# Is it possible to build an app with ruby on rails without controller nor views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I have using ruby on rails for sometime now, but I would like to know if it's possible to build an app without controllers and views?

Comment: Why use a MVC framework at all if your only using the models? Its like ordering a pizza and eating only the pepperoni. You can use ActiveRecord without Rails and there are also other Ruby ORMs.

Answer (score 2):

Just run 
rails new [app-name]  --api --no-sprockets

Answer (score 1):

Without views you can create applicatoin by creating rails api (it won't create views in application). `rails new [api_name]  — api`, but it will create default controller.

Why you don't want controller? If you really don't need controller then you can build the ruby application. Use following command `bundle gem [Application Name]` .

Comment: Create a Rails app. Imagine a you apply for a job posted on Jobapp. There are companies that have many jobs. There a candidates that can apply to jobs. Companies when publishing a job add questions that candidates have to answer when they apply. Questions can be either open (free text) or closed (fixed responses, think a radio button). Questions can be either mandatory or not. 

Your task is to design the data model, i.e. migrations, ActiveRecord models with all the validations, database constraints, indexes, etc. to prepare the data layer for the Jobapp. Don't do any controller or views.

Comment: @AV21 What they mean in that task description is just that you shouldn't flesh out the controller or views, because the focus is on the back-end. _It doesn't mean that there should not be any controllers or views_, like those auto-generated by Rails, for instance. (You may even delete those, if you want, if they introduce noise into the delivery of that task.)